# Click linked image to close / hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is what I have so far. I've tried different solutions, but I'm missing something. :(

Here's is my html:

```
<div class="container"><a class="close-x" href="#">
    <img src="x-close.png" alt="x-close" width="30" height="30" /></a>
<div class="box">Content goes here</div></div>`
```

Here's my css:

```
.container {
    width: 333px;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 30%;
    left: 0;
}
.box {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
a.close-x {
    position: absolute;
    top:-15px;
    right:-15px;
}
```

Here's my attempt at script

http://jsfiddle.net/shanamiami/T6hE9/

Comment: your fiddle doesn't include jquery, add it on the top left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your fiddle is missing jquery library.

Secondly instead of window load use document ready event.

Here is how you can do it:

```
    $(function () { // short way of writing document.ready
    $('div.container a.close-x').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var div = $(this).next('.box').slideToggle();
    });

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/T6hE9/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.ready()` instead of `window.load()`

You can furthur simplify your code.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.close-x').click(function () {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.box').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T6hE9/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.close-x').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var div =$('div.box').slideToggle(); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide more context in your answer? Just posting snippets of code is frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with your code, only minor tweaks required.

1. You just need to include jquery in fiddle
2. whatever code in fiddle's `JavaScript` window, that code is copied inside `window.load` but when you are not on fiddle, make sure to add your code inside `window.load` or `document.ready`.

> ```
> $(window).load(function()
> //your code is copied here by default in fiddle at runtime
> });
> ```